# Exist control in current form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to find out if component with some name exist in current form.
I have name of the component in string variable and if it doesnt exist, i need create it.
I use this code

```
Control c = Controls.Find(New, true)[0];   //najiti komponenty

        if (c == null) {}
```

But it gives me error that the index was outside the bounds of the array.
I know this code is bad, but i dont know to write it good and google dont help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method return an array of controls, i.e. `Control[]`. You are trying to access the first element of the empty array, thus resulting in `IndexOutOfRangeException`
You should try:

```
Control[] controls = Controls.Find(New, true); 
if (controls.Length > 0) 
{
    //logic goes here
}
else 
{
    //no components where found
}
```

Comment: This give me this error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control[]' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'

Comment: You can use `this.Controls.Find(NameOfControl, true).FirstOrDefault()` and then check if the result is `null`.

Answer (score 7):

Try using the Control.ContainsKey() Method, (pass a string variable containg the control name instead of the quoted text in my example):

```
if (!this.Controls.ContainsKey("MyControlName"))
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: Better option*.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if the control is a direct child of the main form. Nested controls will return as false this way.